# What is the difference between "aroma" and "scent"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *aroma* and *scent*? Looking at the NOAD, I would say differences are few.

- Aroma: a distinctive, typically pleasant smell
- Scent: a distinctive smell, especially one that is pleasant

As Italian, I would use *aroma* since that is also an Italian word. Are there cases in which I should rather talk of *scent*?

In Italian, the other word I could use is *profumo* (probably translatable with "scent," in this case), which could be used for *coffee* too as in *Che profumo di caffè!* ("What a […] of coffee!"). Also, in Italian, when explaining the meaning of *aroma* ("aroma"), I would explain it in terms of *profumo*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are times where I would tend to favor one over the other, but I'm having trouble figuring out a simple rule that dictates which one I would choose. I would describe:

- The *aroma* of bread, coffee, and wine, but
- The *scent* of a skunk, a perfume, a flower, or a woman

*Aroma* seems to be the more natural word for describing blends of food and spice, while *scent* seems to be more apt for describing the natural smell of a plant or animal.

Also, not too unlike *atoms* and *molecules*, *scents* seem more fundamental, while *aromas* seem like more of a mixture or blend. So, I might talk about the *scent* of a particular candle, but the *aromas* of the candle store.

Still, the literature has plenty of counterexamples, such as the [scent of bread](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aroma%20of%20bread,scent%20of%20bread&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), or the [aroma of the flower](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aroma+of+the+flower%2Cscent+of+the+flower&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), or the [scent of the wine](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scent+of+the+wine%2C+aroma+of+the+wine&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), so it would be a mistake to interpret any of these thoughts as "rules". The two words are largely synonymous, so there's plenty of room for overlap. If someone said that only one of the two words could be used in a particular context, I'd regard that as [smelling fishy](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/smell+fishy).

Comment: I think "scent of a skunk" is categorically different from your other examples.  In all cases scents are *distinctive* smells, but in the sense "[the smell that an animal or person has, which some animals can follow](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/scent#scent_7)", *pleasant* is not implied.  I think it's this sense where aroma is less likely--an animal has scent glands, not aroma glands.

Comment: In your examples of aromas, you are referring to something that is made from vegetables, or vegetable substances. Can it be that what makes a difference? Even if it is not a _rule_ that is generally valid, could it be used as general guide?

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's not *restricted* to plants, but you are correct.  See sense one in Collins: "[a distinctive usually pleasant smell, esp of spices, wines, and plants](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aroma)"

Comment: @snailplane: You're correct of course. (Incidentally, I included that example on purpose; I was hoping to make that point, but not necessarily explain it. Thanks for your help, your comments have improved my answer considerably.)

Comment: A scent can be unpleasant or neutral (though characteristic). I don't think I've ever found "aroma" used to describe anything less than pleasant, except maybe in ironical context.

Comment: @SF.: Perhaps it's rare, but it [can be found](https://www.google.com/search?q=aroma+of+death&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=%22aroma+of+death%22&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=jn1&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=bks&ei=Bh0pUdFFqLjZBfyggKAE&start=70&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.b2I&fp=25b15d77e0e62e41&biw=1186&bih=846).

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference lies in purpose.

Aromas are where the smell is incidental to what is happening:
 - baking bread, making coffee, sweating.

Scents, on the other hand, have intent:
 - skunks, to scare off predators
 - cat/dog wee, to mark territory
 - perfume, to attract a sexual partner
 - flowers, to attract bees for pollination

Answer (score 0):

In Modern English, both of these words are normally used to refer to pleasant odors; there are other words for unpleasant ones (stink, stench, reek, ...)

English has many pairs of words that mean almost exactly the same thing, because of its many layers of mass borrowings. In this case, *[aroma](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=aroma)* is from Greek via Latin and originally referred to pleasant-smelling herbs for seasoning food with; *[scent](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=scent)* is taken from French *sentir* (which also gives rise to the modern English verb *sense*) and originally referred to the act of tracking a game animal by its smell.

Some of these word-pairs have fine distinctions in their basic meaning: for instance, *wood* and *forest* both can mean an area of land densely covered in trees, but a wood is typically smaller than a forest.  Others don't.  Native speakers choose between these words based on how they fit the rhythm of the larger sentence, or distinctions of tone or connotation that are difficult to describe.  You do not have to worry about whether you have "gotten it wrong" while you are still learning the language.  If you want to improve your ear for the fine distinctions, the best way to go about it is just to read a great deal in the language.